# SignalR and foreverFrame hang with IE 9

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, signalr

I have an asp.net site using SignalR for pushing data from the server to the client . 
I try my page with two browsers (FireFox , IE9)
I noticed , Firefox is using ServerEvent transport and IE uses ForeverFrame .
I have no problem with FF , but in IE9 after some minutes its stop working , I mean I don't get the push events from the server . (When I moved the transport to long poling its working) but I want it to be more efficient without long polling.

In the hub I call the client side each 5 sec.

Please inform me if you need more details .
Any suggestions.

Thanks in advance ...

Comment: After how long does it stop working?

Comment: I didnot measure it exactly , but I think it's after 3 to 5 min , I notice it hangs an don't fire any more .

Comment: What environment are you running under? OS, IIS version .NET version, are you behind any proxies?

Answer (score 0):

Please also see the following https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/blob/master/ReleaseNotes.md
This has the release notes until 1.0.0-rc2 and documents the breaking changes